# Kernel dies and restarts, but there's no error message Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I moved from `Jupyter Notebook` to `Jupyter Lab`, and now when the Kernel dies due to (I assume) memory allocation error, there's no error message saying 'Kernel died'. I only see that the number disappears from the running cell:

[image: jupyter]

The message I get in the console is:

> KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
> kernel 7bb53f39-b0a8-4e32-bbe6-e6dbe7c9c344 restarted

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can confirm I'm also getting this error and I suspect its ram running out, but without any error traces it's really annoying.

Comment: @tgrnie I opened an issue in Github but no answer yet

Comment: @Snow can you link the issue? I'm on the same boat.

Comment: @SiaRezaei unfortunately there wasn't an answer there.

Comment: @Snow I found out mine was an out of memory issue.